# Why AssetManager creation takes tooo long to load that make application start slow

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am making an android app. When I compile and run it (even when I copy and paste apk on device and run) it takes too long to start and show me my first activity.
I debugged logs and found that 1st log as follow takes like 20 seconds then from there after approx 20 seconds I get later logs and app runs.

First log of app:

```
5-19 18:41:42.816 29232-29232/com.softinator.mantrafm D/ResourcesManager: creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.softinator.mantrafm-2/base.apk
```

Comment: Use method tracing to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: I determine trace that why, I said AssetManager take more time to create asset

Comment: did you found any solution @RajendraVerma ?

Comment: No, No . Still I am waiting for some one to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem. Thanks to one of my teammate, basically you'll have to disable "Instant Run" if you are using gradle 2.x

I installed android studio v2 and suddenly this problem came up. 
So basically before giving apk may it be debug apk or production apk, go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run and uncheck "Enable Instant Run to hot swap/resource changes on deploy". You need to disable that and then build apk and give it to somebody else or use yourself.

Regards,

Suyash

Comment: This may solve the problem, in a way, but it feels like a workaround... Instant Run is one of the best things Android Studio introduced as of late, I don't want to disable it.

Comment: Yes don't disable while you test the app. It is one of the best feature. Just disable it before your final build for apk you want to give it to somebody, then enable it back again.